# i have an isuue regrading i am not able to get token from cookie. i am making a next js project with next auth and hasura graphql

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, next-auth

I'm encountering an issue regarding the retrieval of a token from a cookie. I'm currently working on a Next.js project using NextAuth and Hasura GraphQL. With NextAuth, I'm utilizing credential providers for login and token generation, and the generated token is stored in a cookie. However, when it comes to setting up the Apollo client for GraphQL requests, I'm struggling to retrieve the token from the cookie. Despite trying various libraries, I haven't had any luck so far. I'm seeking assistance on how to access the token from the cookie. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!